# Puppet module puppetlabs-apache default run has dependency cycles

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to include puppetlabs-apache module (v1.10.0) in my deploiement, i'm having an issue just by running with default configs

```
puppet apply -e 'include apache'
```

or

```
puppet apply -e 'class { 'apache':
  default_vhost => false, 
  default_ssl_vhost => false,
}'
```

I'm having dependency cycle as follows :

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Found 2 dependency cycles:
(File[15-default-ssl.conf symlink] => File[15-default-ssl.conf symlink])
(File[15-default.conf symlink] => File[15-default.conf symlink])
Try the '--graph' option and opening the resulting '.dot' file in OmniGraffle or GraphViz
```

Any help will be appreciated

```
CentOS 7.1
puppetlabs-apache 1.10.0
puppetdb-4.2.0-1.el7.noarch
puppet-agent-1.5.3-1.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of a missconfiguration in Hiera :

```
apache::vhost_dir:        '/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts'
apache::vhost_enable_dir: '/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts'
```

I think we might add a condition so that the : **apache::vhost_dir** must be different from **apache::vhost_enable_dir** ass well as **apache::mod_dir** must be different from **apache::mod_enable_dir**